# When doing a database engine upgrade to PostgreSQL 12, should the Gemfile be updated for the 'pg' gem as well? How are they related?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, postgresql-9.6, postgres-12

Gemfile specifies `gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'` and the database engine is currently PostgreSQL 9.6 - which needs to be upgraded to PostgreSQL 12. Gemfile.lock includes `pg (0.21.0)` and `pg (0.18.0)`. I don't have a good understanding of how these two are related, if they are at all related. How do the libraries relate to the database engine?

Answer (score 0):

As the homepage of [ruby-pg](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg) suggests that it works with 9.3 and later, I don't think you need to update your Gemfile. All the versions of `pg` gem should support PostgreSQL 9.3 and above.